# Why is sqlsrv not executing in PHP?

Tags: php, sql-server

Why is "extension=php_sqlsrv_53_nts.dll" not loading in my php when I check via `phpinfo()`?

PHP Version 5.3.13  installed on my computer
and 8 DLL php_sqlsrv_* files extracted into the php ext folder.
I added the line extension=php_sqlsrv_53_nts.dll to the php.ini file.

When I refresh my phpinfo, I never see the sqlsrv in there..

Any ideas?

Comment: IIS or Apache (or something else)?  Which version of the sqlsrv drivers did you download, 2.0 or 3.0?  Have you double-checked "thread safety" in phpinfo() to ensure it is disabled?  Are you editing the correct php.ini (depending on installation and web-server there may be multiple for cgi, cli and module)?

Comment: After doing everything I could think of, It was a simple matter of uncommenting the extension_dir = "ext" ,, finally got it working, Thanks

Comment: Matt H. I am using
Ultimate goal: To install wordpress in IIS with MSSQL (sqlsvr method)

Configuration as below,
1. Web server - IIS, 
2. mssql driver 3.0,
3. sqlsrv NOT PDO,
4. PHP version 5.4.3 (PHP-CGI.exe Path is in D: loaded which is present in wamp. Since couldn't get any php-cgi.exe along with php file from php.net )
5. MSSQL 2008
6.